# Controlling the priority of children's handlers for the same keyboard event

Tags: winforms

I have multiple children of the same WinForms form, each with its own handler for a keyboard event. For a minimal example (C#):

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    c1 = new Control();
    c2 = new Control();
    c1.KeyPress += c1_KeyPress;
    c2.KeyPress += c2_KeyPress;
    Controls.Add(c1);
    Controls.Add(c2);
}

void c1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    Text += " c1";
    e.Handled = true;
}

void c2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    Text += " c2";
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

When the event fires, it always gets handled by whichever child was originally added to the form first. Reordering the children with `c2.BringToFront()` or `Controls.SetChildIndex(c2, 0)` doesn't change the priority. Reordering the constructions or the delegate assignments doesn't change anything either. Calling `c2.Focus()` doesn't either. Changing the order of the `Add` calls is the only thing that seems to affect it.

(By contrast, for *mouse events* the priority gets resolved in an expected way: the topmost control under the pointer hotspot gets dibs on the event, and "topmost" is a clear concept I can control using `BringToFront` and friends.)

In my real case, `c1` is a simple custom control derived from `WinForms.UserControl`, and `c2` is a [`CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser`](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.WinForms/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs). There the keyboard events are caught by `c2` no matter what I do.

What decides this priority of handlers? How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "priority", keyboard events are raised on the control that has the focus.  Intuitively simple to understand, entering text in a TextBox requires selecting it first.  A very significant flaw in the posted snippet is that you cannot tell which one has the focus.  Although the Control class is usable as-is, in practice you almost always need to derive your own class from it to give it desirable behavior.

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Replace `new Control()` with `new MyControl()`.  Now you can tell.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyControl : Control {
    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e) {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }
    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e) {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnLeave(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        if (this.Focused) {
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, this.DisplayRectangle);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, and explicitly calling `c2.Focus()`, and still the keyboard events go to `c1`. Am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: The usual mistake with calling Focus() is to do so when the control is not visible yet.  That doesn't happen until later, the Shown event is the first signal.  Use Select() instead.